# How does DotNetCore-publish task in Azure Devops build pipeline get access to build output without explicitly specifying it?

Tags: azure-devops

I copied the below YAML equivalent template from a working Classic pipeline:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: DotNetCore-build
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: 'abc.Host/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build_output'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: DotNetCore-publish
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: 'abc.Host/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

As per my understanding, the task "DotNetCore-build" will build the project and export the output to `D:\a\1\s\build_output\`
My understanding is that the output from `D:\a\1\s\build_output\` will be used by "DotNetCore-publish" task to do the publish to `D:\a\1\a (build.artifactstagingdirectory)`.
However, nowhere in the "DotNetCore-publish" task it asks for the output from the "DotNetCore-build" task. It only uses the project file as input for the publish task.

I need to understand how the publish task is able to complete its task even though the build output path `--output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build_output` is nowhere explicitly provided. The build is getting completed and I want to be sure that the artifacts are correct.

Comment: Both tasks are part of the same job, correct?

Comment: Yes, they are part of the same job